# Why does this regex throw an exception?

Tags: c++, regex, exception, c++11

I am trying to use `std::regex_replace` in C++11 (Visual Studio 2013) but the regex i am trying to create is throwing an exception:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x0030ED34
```

Why is this the case? This is my definition:

```
std::string regexStr = R"(\([A - Za - z] | [0 - 9])[0 - 9]{2})";

std::regex rg(regexStr); <-- This is where the exception thrown

line = std::regex_replace(line, rg, this->protyp->getUTF8Character("$&"));
```

What i want to do: Find all matches inside a string which are of the following format:

"\X99" OR "\999" 
where X = A-Z or a-z and 9 = 0-9.

I also tried to use the boost regex library, but it also throws an exeception.

(Another question: Can i use the backreference as i am doing in the last line? I want to replace dynamically according to the match)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you have spaces around `-` in the character classes?

Comment: The problem with your regexp is that the parentheses aren't balanced. One of the opening parentheses is escaped, so it doesn't match the closing parenthesis.

Comment: @puelo `\\[A-Za-z\d]\d{2}\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above comments, you need to fix your regex: to match a literal backslash you need to use `"\\\\"` (or `R("\\")`).

My code that shows all the first captured groups:

```
string line = "\\X99 \\999";
string regexStr = "(\\\\([A-Za-z]|[0-9])[0-9]{2})";
regex rg(regexStr); //<-- This is where the exception was thrown before
smatch sm;
while (regex_search(line, sm, rg)) {
        std::cout << sm[1] << std::endl;
        line = sm.suffix().str();
    }
```

Output:

```
\X99
\999
```

Regarding using a method call inside a *replacement string*, I do not find such a functionality in the [regex_replace documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace):

> **fmt**    -   the regex replacement format string, exact syntax depends on the
>   value of flags